# Not using Application Context and autowired dependencies failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, service, controller

I'm doing a SPRING MVC project, i didnt see someone with the same config as me, since im not using a .xml file but 3 class to configure the ApplicationContext equivalent. If you find problem to read, i cant barely post more.. StackOverflow doesnt allow me to publish in more detail the containt of mthe specific interfaces needed for my Service.Impl and DAO.impl

**Application Config Package**

```java
package com.jumalu.spring.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScans;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import static org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.*;

@Configuration      
@PropertySource("classpath:db.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement 
@ComponentScans(value = {
        @ComponentScan("com.jumalu.spring.dao.impl"),
        @ComponentScan("com.jumalu.spring.service.impl")
})
public class AppConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        Properties props = new Properties();

        // setting JDBC properties
        props.put(DRIVER, env.getProperty("mysql.driver"));
        props.put(URL, env.getProperty("mysql.url"));
        props.put(USER, env.getProperty("mysql.user"));
        props.put(PASS, env.getProperty("mysql.password"));

        //setting hibernate properties
        props.put(SHOW_SQL, env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        props.put(HBM2DDL_AUTO, env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));

        // setting c3p0 properties
        props.put(C3P0_MIN_SIZE, env.getProperty("hibernate.c3p0.min_size"));
        props.put(C3P0_MAX_SIZE, env.getProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_size"));
        props.put(C3P0_ACQUIRE_INCREMENT, env.getProperty("hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment"));
        props.put(C3P0_TIMEOUT, env.getProperty("hibernate.c3p0.timeout"));
        props.put(C3P0_MAX_STATEMENTS, env.getProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements"));

        factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(props);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.jumalu.spring.entities");
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory().getObject());

        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

```java
package com.jumalu.spring.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MyWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {AppConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }

}
```

```java
package com.jumalu.spring.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.jumalu.spring.controller"})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
}
```

**Now the Controller Package**

```java
package com.jumalu.spring.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.jumalu.spring.entities.Affaire;
import com.jumalu.spring.service.interfaces.IAffaireService;

@CrossOrigin("*")
@RestController
public class AffaireController {

    @Autowired
    private IAffaireService affaireService;
}
```

**Now may DAO.impl package**

```java
package com.jumalu.spring.dao.impl;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.jumalu.spring.dao.interfaces.IAffaireDAO;
import com.jumalu.spring.entities.Affaire;

@Repository
public class AffaireDAO extends ManagerDAO<Affaire> implements IAffaireDAO {

@Override
    // a method
}
}
```

```java
package com.jumalu.spring.dao.impl;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


import com.jumalu.spring.dao.interfaces.IDAO;

@Repository("daoGeneric")
public class ManagerDAO<T> implements IDAO<T> {

    @Autowired  
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

// + CRUD method
}
}
```

**Now the Service.Impl**

```java
package com.jumalu.spring.service.impl;

import com.jumalu.spring.service.interfaces.IAffaireService;
import java.util.List;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.jumalu.spring.dao.interfaces.IAffaireDAO;
import com.jumalu.spring.entities.Affaire;

@Service
@Transactional
public class AffaireService extends ManagerService<Affaire> implements IAffaireService {

    @Override
    // a method
}
```

```java
package com.jumalu.spring.service.impl;

import java.util.List;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.jumalu.spring.dao.interfaces.IDAO;
import com.jumalu.spring.service.interfaces.IService;

@Service
@Transactional
public class ManagerService<T> implements IService<T> {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("daoGeneric")
    IDAO<T> DAO ;

    @Override
    // + another bunch of CRUD Method
}
```

the problem i have ::

```java
Error creating bean with name 'affaireController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.jumalu.spring.service.interfaces.IAffaireService com.jumalu.spring.controller.AffaireController.affaireService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.jumalu.spring.service.interfaces.IAffaireService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:539)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:986)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4978)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5290)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.jumalu.spring.service.interfaces.IAffaireService com.jumalu.spring.controller.AffaireController.affaireService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.jumalu.spring.service.interfaces.IAffaireService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.jumalu.spring.service.interfaces.IAffaireService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:543)
    ... 28 more

août 31, 2019 2:43:29 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
GRAVE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'affaireController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.jumalu.spring.service.interfaces.IAffaireService com.jumalu.spring.controller.AffaireController.affaireService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.jumalu.spring.service.interfaces.IAffaireService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:539)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:986)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4978)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5290)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.jumalu.spring.service.interfaces.IAffaireService com.jumalu.spring.controller.AffaireController.affaireService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.jumalu.spring.service.interfaces.IAffaireService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.jumalu.spring.service.interfaces.IAffaireService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:543)
    ... 28 more

août 31, 2019 2:43:29 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
GRAVE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'affaireController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.jumalu.spring.service.interfaces.IAffaireService com.jumalu.spring.controller.AffaireController.affaireService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.jumalu.spring.service.interfaces.IAffaireService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:667)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:539)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:493)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:986)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4978)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5290)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.jumalu.spring.service.interfaces.IAffaireService com.jumalu.spring.controller.AffaireController.affaireService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.jumalu.spring.service.interfaces.IAffaireService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.jumalu.spring.service.interfaces.IAffaireService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:543)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: That's not _the entire problem you have_ post _the entire error message_. (That said, the problem is almost certainly that you're only component-scanning a portion of your application. Additionally, you should use Spring Boot in new applications, Spring Data will create DAOs for you automatically, and it is not customary to add `I` to interface names in Java.)

Comment: hello, Im alsao pretty sure it's a component scanning problem. but i've scanned the necessary package when i implement my Service and Repository which are **com.jumalu.spring.dao.impl** and **com.jumalu.spring.service.impl**

Comment: I fixed the problem.. it was my used of RestController instead of Controller in my Controller package. Since RestController was a Controller + RequestBody i thought i could use it but looks like no, i cant

Comment: It's _also_ `@ResponseBody`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in you component scan configuration in `AppConfig`.

Your `IAffaireService` extends `ManagerService` which is trying to autowire `ManagerDAO`, which is in package **com.inti.dao.impl**, which is not included in `@ComponentScan`

Include it and it will solve the issue,

```
@ComponentScans(value = {
    @ComponentScan("com.jumalu.spring.dao.impl"),
    @ComponentScan("com.jumalu.spring.service.impl"),
    @ComponentScan("com.jumalu.spring.service.impl")
```

})

Comment: Hello, That was an error of mine when editing my message.. I made a mistake when i wrote my message since i have 3 eclipse open, i took a manager from an other project. now i've just edited the ManagerDAO corresponding to my project and i didnt touch anything else. i look you look at my AppConfig, i had already used it. It's a component scanning problem yet i think i've scanned the necessary package but the problem happen.